# How to secure communication between IoT Devices and Azure IoT-Hub?

Tags: security, azure-iot-hub, opc, opc-ua

My setup looks like this:

In my local envirenment I have an OPC server which reads data from local OPC devices and send them to my local little server which then sends the data to the IoT-Hub on Azure (and there I save the data to the cosmosDB).

The local little server which communicates to the IoT-Hub on Azure [looks like this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-iot-device?activeTab=readme):

```
var connectionString = '[IoT Hub device connection string]';
// use factory function from AMQP-specific package
var clientFromConnectionString = require('azure-iot-device-amqp').clientFromConnectionString;

// AMQP-specific factory function returns Client object from core package
var client = clientFromConnectionString(connectionString);

// use Message object from core package
var Message = require('azure-iot-device').Message;

var connectCallback = function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Could not connect: ' + err);
  } else {
    console.log('Client connected');
    var msg = new Message('some data from my device');
    client.sendEvent(msg, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.toString());
      } else {
        console.log('Message sent');
      };
    });
  };
};


client.open(connectCallback);
```

How Can I make sure that this communication is secure?

Comment: What do you mean with secure?

Comment: This is OPC irrelevant question so why tagging it with OPC-UA?

Comment: @astrowalker it is relevant in the whole communication chain from the device over opc-ua to the cloud over amqp.

Comment: @PeterBons I mean do I need certificates or some other security mechanisms here? or can I run this solution for a whole factory?

Answer (score 0):

IoT Hub requires all connection to be secured via TLS (see [IoT Hub MQTT Support](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support.md) ) and it only uses the secure version 1.2 (see [IoT Hub TLS deprecating 1.0 and 1.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-tls-deprecating-1-0-and-1-1)).

This will secure your transport (by default).

In production environment I would use X509 certificates to also secure identity and integrity. 
To do so, please have a look at [IoT Hub Security x509 Get Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-security-x509-get-started) to learn how to get and register certificates at IoT hub. And have a look at this [Sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/device/samples/simple_sample_device_x509.js) 
 which shows how to use X509 certificate in node.js code to connect to IoT hub.